# How can I stop my AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I go to the running instances panel, right click on the instance and hover over **"instance state"** the `Stop` option is grayed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance needs an EBS volume as its root device in order to stop it.

Comment: Is there a way to change that config?

Comment: Not for a running instance. You'll have to launch a new instance from an AMI that is backed by EBS (where the root device type is "EBS" and not "instance store")